# Table created with Django has no content after view finishes

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I have a Django view that does some complex SQL queries and which contains code like the following:

```
sql1 = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table ..."
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql1)
...
sql2 = "INSERT INTO my_temp_table ..."
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql2)
```

The queries are more complicated than this, but the idea should be clear: I create a temp table, then insert a bunch of stuff into it, which I use later on in the view.  This works -- it is obvious, based on the view's performance, that the table is being created and the stuff is being inserted into it.

However, in the course of adding a feature I wanted to inspect the results of what got inserted into **my_temp_table** in order to refine some of the queries that use it.  So for exploratory purposes I changed the SQL to just create a regular table, so I could examine it afterward.  So *sql1* became, in effect:

```
sql1 = "CREATE TABLE my_temp_table ..."
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql1)
```

In other words, everything's the same except **my_temp_table** is created without the "TEMPORARY" modifier.

The problem is that, when the query has finished, the **my_temp_table** table is empty -- none of the data that got inserted into it (in the *sql2* query) is actually in it after the view is finished.  This is puzzling -- clearly the data was successfully inserted into **my_test_table** in the course of view execution, since otherwise the view wouldn't be able to do the stuff that it is clearly doing.  But where did the data go?

[One additional confirmation that the data actually *was* in the table at one point is the fact that I can log the query, then manually run the same query by hand, and everything works like I'd expect.]

I'm running this with Django's testserver (via manage.py runserver) using Django 1.4.2.

Comment: Sounds like a transaction issue to me. Are you sure the transaction is committed at the end of the view?

Comment: That's what I thought, too, but nothing is changed from a transaction pov in changing from a temporary table to a non-temporary table [right?] unless there's some weird thing where you can write to a table, then read from a table, and then have the transaction not go through; although then you'd think the table wouldn't be created at all.  Aside from that, Django dox claim default behavior is to have per-view transactions that commit unless an error occurs, and no error is occurring.  Unless doing this SQL by hand changes that...

Comment: Well, in MySQL DDL commands are not considered part of a transaction, so it's perfectly understandable that the table gets created but the data is not visible. As for writing then reading it back, again that's what you'd expect if you were within a single transaction.

Comment: I added a transaction.commit_unless_managed() after all the DB stuff, and now the data remains in the table.  The DDL command not being part of the transaction was the crucial missing piece.  Although I'm still confused as to why this wasn't auto-committed, which the documentation suggests is the normal case, and which seems to be happening elsewhere.  Must be a result of not touching the ORM here.  Anyway, thanks!